# Problem passing NSMutableArray between classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I've been trying for hours to try and get this to work, but I can't seem to do it. The user pressed a button, which calls 'newPalette' in HandlingPalettes, and then pushes in SingleView. Here's all the revelant code I have:

HandlingPalettes.h:

```
@interface HandlingPalettes : UIViewController {

NSMutableArray *navBarColour;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *navBarColour;

-(void)newPalette;

@end
```

HandlingPalettes.m:

```
#import "HandlingPalettes.h"
#import "SingleView.h"



@implementation HandlingPalettes

@synthesize navBarColour;


-(void)newPalette {

    UIColor *colourOfNavBar = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.25 alpha:1];
    if (navBarColour == nil) {
        navBarColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:colourOfNavBar, nil];
        currentPalette = 0;
    }
    else {
        [navBarColour addObject:colourOfNavBar];
        currentPalette = navBarColour.count-1;
    }

    NSLog(@"Number: %i", navBarColour.count);

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

SingleView.h:

```
#import "HandlingPalettes.h"


@interface SingleView : UIViewController {

}

HandlingPalettes *handlingPalettes;

@end
```

SingleView.m:

```
#import "SingleView.h"

@implementation SingleView


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    handlingPalettes = [[HandlingPalettes alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Second number: %i", handlingPalettes.navBarColour.count);
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [handlingPalettes release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

The problem I have is that NSLog returns:

Number: 1
Second Number: 0

And then going back to the first view and pressing the button again..

Number: 2
Second Number: 0

And again..

Number 3:
Second Number: 0

Can somebody help me and explain why this isn't working?

Thanks so much.

Comment: It should pass on the array so that the count is the same in both areas.

Comment: post the method that is invoked when you press the button

Comment: however I'm pretty sure that you just push the newly created view controller. That is what KingofBliss answered. He is right.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a different instance to HandlingPalettes class. You should use singleton to do so.

handlingPalettes in handlingPalettes.m and handlingPalettes in SingleView are always different. So use singleton class, or use appDelegate to access in different class.

Comment: +1,Yes, making object in different class reinitalize the array.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain this more?

Comment: You are creating a new instance to the class handlingPalettes, this will allocate a new memory location for handlingPalettes.color, But the old one will be in some other memory location. So it produces different value

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace this line in `HandlingPalettes.m`

```
navBarColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:colourOfNavBar, nil];
```

with this

```
self.navBarColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:colourOfNavBar, nil];
```

And you need change here

```
@interface SingleView : UIViewController {

}

HandlingPalettes *handlingPalettes; //not here

@end
```

correct

```
 @interface SingleView : UIViewController {

   HandlingPalettes *handlingPalettes;    

    }



    @end
```

Edit:

Because it reinitialize the array.so you need either you make this array in same class or make in appDelegate class. because app delegate class not reintialize it.

Comment: Unfortunately after making these changes, it returned the same result.